# How to make the list from concat function and apply it to firstworkdate in Qlik

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a problem with my set analysis. I want to show the CONCAT function result as list. And apply to Firstworkdate as list Holiday.

My set analysis is:

```
firstworkdate('01/01/2018',6,concat({<checkwd{'0'}>}tradedate,','))
```

with `checkwd` is used to determine working date or not. If 0 is Holiday

thanks for your help !

Comment: actually, My set is: firstworkdate('01/01/2018',6,concat({<checkwd={'0'}>}tradedate,',')). But it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a variable (`vConcateTradeDate` for example) and set its content to:

`= chr(39) & concat( {< checkwd = {'0'} >} tradedate, chr(39) & ', ' & chr(39) ) & chr(39)`

And then use this variable in your calculation:

`= firstworkdate('01/01/2018', 6, $(vConcateTradeDate))`

Having these values in the `tradedate` field:

```
 01/01/2018
 01/02/2018
 01/03/2018
 01/04/2018
 01/05/2018
 01/06/2018
 01/07/2018
```

The `vConcateTradeDate` will return:

```
'01/01/2018', '01/02/2018', '01/03/2018', '01/04/2018', '01/05/2018', '01/06/2018', '01/07/2018'
```

Comment: Hi Stefan Stoichev, thanks for your reply but it doesnt work like what I want. In this example above I expect this result is 22 Dec 2017 but it just show 25 Dec 2017. It means, this set analysis can't detect this list holiday vconcateTradedate. If have any idea, please help me. Thanks alot

Comment: hmm this is strange. I can see 22nd as a result. This is what i can see (script used, variable value and the text box expression and result) 
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xZRwJ8FTnqp556aeHJMh9vS7zj999aFP